# My java project with openCV, does not load the library outside the IDE using .jar

Tags: java, opencv, java-8

I managed to run my facial detection project with java using OpenCV, but when I load it into the IDE, it just opens the JAR without loading a library.
example: the person's image does not appear when you click to show the face.

Comment: Could you add more details? What IDE you are using? How exactly You are creating a project there?

Comment: apologies for the delay, i use the Netbeans 8.2, Java-8, I'm creating a mini project. The program only works when I put the dist folder in C: I was wondering if the user can choose where to put it, so I can send it to the path variable. I thought about using Setup, but I couldn't create it.
Here is the program's github: https://github.com/AdrielCavalcante/Facial-detection-Java @SergeiSirik